# AWS Beanstalk going out of memory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have set up elastic beanstalk with **m5.large** instance type but after running for sometime on production... it is throwing the below error -

[Tue Jan 28 09:44:37.840041 2020] [mpm_worker:error] [pid 30733:tid 140584956389440] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00283: fork: Unable to fork new process

And hence It causes the server to go down. What could be the possible solutions guys?

Answer (score 1):

1. The m5 large contains 8GB RAM, so try to move it to m5.xlarge if it requires more memory for your App/DB
2. This is usually caused by insufficient swap file space. Sometimes without it, the system has to through fork operations even if it has sufficient free RAM
3. Tune the mysql database server configuration and my apache configuration to use a lot less memory.
4. Allocate more +GB's of swap drive you won't run out of memory even if that swap drive isn't used for 99.9% of the time

Comment: Ok... so i need to create swap file using .ebextension folder or there is another manual method for increasing swap drive space?

Comment: It depends upon your OS environment. In Linux/ubuntu you need to create it in /var/swapfile and in the AIX server need to create a paging space.